# Can I use /etc/init/ on Debian Wheezy to manage a daemon process?

Tags: debian-wheezy, daemon, upstart, init

I want to run a PHP daemon process and found a solution at [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2036654/run-php-script-as-daemon-process#16577806) but unfortunately its not working. Now I thought Upstart is not installed since Debian still uses System V. I have two questions now. Why does `/etc/init/` exist and can I add a Upstart config file there to make a daemon or do I have to use `start-stop-daemon` instead?

Comment: Why isn't it possible just to write an init (shell) script that starts the daemon? Or do you require monitoring or something?

Comment: @mtak It should automatically respawn. Thats not possible with start-stop-daemon.